# Code cannot remove selected Marker from Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi there I got the following code, where I am trying to add few marker randomly. Then in the second function, trying to delete selected marker. But my markerCoin [i].setMap(null); line seems to have no effect and it doesn't delete the selected marker. Also it does not produce any error.

```
var markerCoin=[]; // Global Variable

    function addMarker(){
  var max = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -0.0005 : 0.0005; 
  var min=Math.random() < 0.5 ? -0.0001 : 0.0001;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    markerCoin [i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat+ ( Math.random() * (max - min) + min), myLng+ ( Math.random() * (max - min) + min)),
      map: map
    });

    targetLat[i]=markerCoin[i].getPosition().lat();
    targetLng[i]=markerCoin[i].getPosition().lng();


  }
}

function markerDelete() {
  var distance;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (targetLat[i]!=0) {
      distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(myLat,myLng,targetLat[i],targetLng[i]);
    }

    if (distance <= 30) {
      alert(distance);
      markerCoin [i].setMap(null);**//it does not remove the marker.**
      targetLat[i]=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions, what is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: After the alert, can you check if markerCoin[i] is indeed a marker object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
  var markerCoin=[];
  var targetLat=[];
  var targetLng=[];

  function addMarker(){
    var max = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -0.0005 : 0.0005; 
    var min = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -0.0001 : 0.0001;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      markerCoin[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( myLat + ( Math.random() * (max - min) + min), myLng + ( Math.random() * (max - min) + min)),
        map: map
      });

      targetLat[i]=markerCoin[i].getPosition().lat();
      targetLng[i]=markerCoin[i].getPosition().lng();


    }
  }

  function markerDelete() {
    var distance;

    if (targetLat[i]!=0) {
      distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(myLat,myLng,targetLat[i],targetLng[i]);
    }

    if (distance <= 30) {

      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        markerCoin[i].setMap(null);
        targetLat[i]=0;
      }
    }
  }

  addMarker();
  markerDelete();
```

Checkout [this slightly modified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1099/).

Comment: With my different test environments, I was having problem in MaC+Safari combination. Just tested in other environment and seems like working. I will update with further updates.

Comment: I just tested it on Mac/Safari, and it seems to work as expected. Made small update here: https://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1100/

Comment: Thanks ArcaneCraeda, thanks for the fiddle as well. Not sure what went wrong at my end. But I can see the above code to add and delete marker works in all the environment including mac/safari.